# Using apps from two countries on the same device

Tags: google-play-store, 7.1-nougat

I split my time between Canada and US among other places. Let's say I have things like bank accounts in both countries, and it is often the case that the mobile banking app for a bank is only available in the play store for the country the bank is based in<sup>1</sup>.

My phone is connected to the US app store, and my payment information is from the US, so I can get all the US apps fine. Is there any way I can get the Canadian apps as well? I don't want to permanently change my app store country, but adding another account or something would be fine. I don't need any paid apps on the Canadian side, only free ones.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is the case for TD Canada, for example, which only makes its app available on the Canadian app store. The other big banks, however, all put their app on the US store as well.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a second Google account should work. If you're in the US and you're trying to download Canadian apps try this:

(It worked for me without the vpn but you can try with)

1.Download a vpn from play store. Make sure it's one that allows you to choose the county your 'in'

2.Turn off location on your phone

3.After successfully setting up the vpn, to the desired county, add a Google account to your phone (settings/accounts/Google/and account.) 
You might need to create new account in case Google 'knows' your spare accounts location

4.Now, go into play store, open the menu and change the account to the one you just added. Try downloading the app.

After that you could switch between accounts within the play store app depending on which apps you need to download

Comment: If you don't want to add new account, you can go to payments.google.com and manager your billing info and country from there.