# google cloud print registered printers from my device

Tags: printing

I have a printer (HP laser Jet 1020) plugged to my computer via usb. I've also added the printer to my google cloud print successfully by following [this](https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197?hl=fr&ref_topic=4456286).

My goal is to be able to print using my Android (A7) . using Chrome => share => print => All printers , I get only "Officejet Pro plugin for HP and Samsung" . I'm not able to list my google cloud printers. I've also tried to add Google Cloud print application from the store and got " the article is not available in my country".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the chrome app is logged into the same Google account as the printer is connected to. To confirm that, go into "chrome" -> "settings" on the top of the page it will show the account that chrome is connected to.

If that doesn't work, see if clearing data of the chrome app does the trick. (Settings>apps>chrome>storage>manage space>clear data.)

You can also try [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/185787/241679) trick, to install apps that are not available in your country.