# Want to change country in Google Play store

Tags: google-play-store, nexus-5, lineageos

This is not duplicate of other questions. I've been struggling with this issue for last 3 weeks and have contacted Google over chat, forums and other avenues too without any luck.

I moved from USA to India and now some of the apps can't be downloaded due to payments profile being in USA with an active Google Domains subscription.

So far I've tried following steps -

- Went to payments.google.com and created another profile with India as country. Now I can see two payment profiles as USA and India.
- Added credit cards etc so that it's a valid one
- Went to Apps > Play Store and cleared cache and data. Removed my google account and restarted my phone to add Google account again.
- Can't delete my cc info from USA payments profile due to active Google Domains subscription. Tried cancelling it, but it takes me to Domains billing page which again asks me to go back to payments page to cancel. So kind of catch 22 situation here.
- Unless I cancel Google Domains subscription, can't close my USA payments profile.
- Went to Google play to purchase something and it doesn't allow me to buy anything with India card, so other solution to at least reach 'Accept & Buy' stage can't be done.

I'm stuck with USA google play store now and would appreciate any help to change country so as to get to useful apps.

Comment: Just to be sure, you clicked on the drop down arrow and actually switched your profile to India, right? I have both of them active and can switch between the two

Comment: You removed your Google account and then added the same one back? Maybe try adding a different one back? Like here https://android.stackexchange.com/a/185787/241679

Answer (score 0):

One option to do that is going into your [**Google Wallet Setting**](https://pay.google.com/gp/w/u/0/home/settings) and add a new profile for that Country / Region

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**You are allowed to change the country of your account once a year.  If you have moved permanently, you can change it under Accounts**

- Settings
- See All Settings
- Accounts and Imports
- Other Google Account Settings
- Payments and subscriptions

Method-1

- Manage Payment Methods
- Select a card and change the address
- If there aren't any, just add a new card with the desired address.

Method-2

- Settings
- Edit Name and Address

**If you have not moved permanently**

- Create a new Google account with the desired address
- Add it as an account on your mobile
- When required, just switch the account for the country.

Some apps are more determined and require a VPN to that country as well as an account change.  I do this routinely with my multiple accounts and vpn.

Answer (score -1):

Add a new gmail account to your phone.  In Google Play app, select the new gmail account using the drop down arrow, then set everything up using your new country address and cards :)

Comment: While this would work in theory. "Use a different account" is an extreme - last option - measure.

You will never be able to consolidate apps and payment profiles after this, and backups will not be enabled on the apps purchased from the second device, considering backups are tied to a single account.

Comment: @RaghdHamzeh - this is incorrect.  I have 5 accounts for various countries.  For account related activities you can just switch the account in playstore.